# Php Mysql Query not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name tblnetworkstatus and I have 11 columns

1. Id
2. issue_name
3. affected_server
4. affected_service
5. issue_type
6. priority
7. duration
8. status
9. start_date
10. end_date
11. description

I am getting id in affected_server and affected_service which I am storing in my DB, now I have three situations

1. Either both affected_server and affected_service has been selected
2. Only affected_server is selected
3. Only affected_service is selected

I am getting the name of affected_server and affected_service from tblserver and tblproducts respectively using join on three tables tblnetworkstatus,tblserver and tblproduct I already have the following query got from here

```
SELECT 
    m.issue_name ,m.issue_type ,
    m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,
    m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,
    s.name  as server_name,p.name as product_name
    from mod_networkstatus as m 
    LEFT JOIN  tblservers as  s  ON  m.affected_server=s.id
    LEFT JOIN tblproducts as  p  ON  m.affected_service=p.id
```

But If I have multiple id's of affected_server and affected_service like I am storing 1,2,3,4 in a single column affected_server or affected_service then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use union as it will give a lots of **duplicate data**

What you want to achieve can be done with simple `left join` or `inner join`

```
    SELECT 
    m.issue_name ,m.issue_type ,
    m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,
    m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,
    s.name  as server_name,p.name as product_name
    from mod_networkstatus as m 
    LEFT JOIN  tblservers as  s  ON  m.affected_server=s.id
    LEFT JOIN tblproducts as  p  ON  m.affected_service=p.id
```

---

> for multiple id's in one column

```
    SELECT 
    m.issue_name ,m.issue_type ,
    m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,
    m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,
    s.name  as server_name,p.name as product_name
    from mod_networkstatus as m 
    LEFT JOIN  tblservers as  s  ON  FIND_IN_SET(m.affected_server,s.id)
    LEFT JOIN tblproducts as  p  ON  m.affected_service=p.id
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: If i have multiple items selected then the affected_server column have id's like that 1,2,3 then how can I do that on mutiple id's on single column...

Comment: You need to use `field_in_set` something like this `ON FIND_IN_SET(sometable.id, othertable.ids)`

Comment: take a reference from here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set. i also havent used that but knowns that it can do the job

Comment: SELECT 
    m.issue_name ,m.issue_type ,</br>
    m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,</br>
    m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,</br>
    s.name  as server_name,p.name as product_name</br>
    from mod_networkstatus as m </br>
    LEFT JOIN  tblservers as  s  ON  </br>FIND_IN_SET(s.id,m.affected_server)
    </br>LEFT JOIN tblproducts as  p  ON  </br>FIND_IN_SET(p.id,m.affected_service)

This query works but it gives me the duplicate record only the affected_server is changed but I want this in a single row like that
server1,server2

Answer (score 0):

Even your requirement is not much clear, still as per understanding your requirement you can use below query.

```
SELECT m.issue_name ,m.issue_type ,m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,s.name  AS server_name,p.name AS product_name 
FROM  tblnetworkstatus m 
LEFT JOIN tblservers s ON m.affected_server=s.id 
LEFT JOIN tblproducts p ON m.affected_service=p.id 
WHERE ((m.affected_server='Y' AND m.affected_service='Y') OR m.affected_server='Y' OR m.affected_service='Y');
```

Note: If it is not what you want then please share all 3 tables sample data and your desired output, so that I can help you.

As per your latest update, you can try it-

```
SELECT m.issue_name ,m.issue_type ,m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,s.name  AS server_name,p.name AS product_name 
FROM  tblnetworkstatus m 
LEFT JOIN tblservers s ON find_in_set(s.id,m.affected_server) 
LEFT JOIN tblproducts p ON find_in_set(p.id,m.affected_service) 
WHERE ((m.affected_server='Y' AND m.affected_service='Y') OR m.affected_server='Y' OR m.affected_service='Y');
```

Note: But this is not a good idea as it will not use index and slow the process.

Comment: yes but it gives me duplicate records which i don;t want 

I want to show like that affected_server=server1,server2,server3 etc